# How to optimize this for loop faster than O(N^3)?

Tags: performance, for-loop, time-complexity

My for loop prints all the consecutive subsequence of a list. For example, suppose a list contains [0, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]. It prints,

- 0
- 0,1
- 0,1,2
- 0,1,2,3
- ........
- 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
- 1
- 1,2
- 1,2,3
- 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
- ........
- 8
- 8,9
- 9

```
for i in range(10)
    for j in range(i, 10):
        subseq = []
            for k in range(i, j+1):
                subseq.append(k)
        print(subseq)
```

The current algorithmic complexity of this for loop is O(N^3). Is there any way to make this  algorithm any faster?

Comment: Don't follow your loops, but this feels like O(N^2) problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Python (this is Python, right?), but something like this will be a little faster version of `O(N^3)` (see comments below):

```
for i in range(10):
    subseq = []
    for j in range(i, 10):
        subseq.append(j)
        print(subseq)
```

Yes, that works:

```
[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[1]
[1, 2] 
...
[7, 8]
[7, 8, 9]
[8]
[8, 9]
[9]
```

Comment: Cool! I don't know why this never occured to me. I had to compute something with the subseq list and i guess my brain thought finish making the subseq list and then do something with it after the for loop. Thank you!

Comment: This actually takes time O(n^3). While there are only two loops here, remember that printing the subarray takes time O(n) because there can be up to n items in that subarray.

Comment: @templatetypedef Would it make the code from question O(n^4)?

Comment: Nope, it would still be O(n^3). The reason why is that the extra loop to build up the current elements array does (asymptotically) as much work as printing out those elements. It's definitely slower than what you have here, though, since it's rebuilding subarrays from scratch each time rather than recycling the work.

Comment: @templatetypedef thank you! corrected my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It’s not possible to do this in less than O(n<sup>3</sup>) time because you’re printing a total of O(n<sup>3</sup>) items. Specifically, split the array in quarters and look at the middle two quarters of the array. Pick any element there - say, the one at position k. That will be printed in at least n<sup>2</sup> / 4 different subarrays: pick any element in the first quarter, any element in the last quarter, and the subarray between those elements will contain the element at position k.

This means that any of the n / 2 items in the middle two quarters gets printed at least n<sup>2</sup> / 4 times, so you print at least n<sup>3</sup> / 8 total values. There’s no way to do that in better than O(n<sup>3</sup>) time.